# Create menu with telegram and javascript

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I am currently using app script to make a telegram bot that replies and reads the messages.
I created a menu with buttons, but the following buttons only work to read the boxes of the google sheet. Instead, I would like the buttons to work only to change the sheet, and after I changed the sheet, the possibility to do the search by text returns.

Thank you

```js
function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function sendKeyboard(chatId, text, keyboard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}

function doPost(e) {

  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  var keyboard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [{
        "text": "Button1",
        "callback_data": "Button1"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Button2",
        "callback_data": "Button2"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Button3",
        "callback_data": "Button3"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Button4",
        "callback_data": "Button4"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Button5",
        "callback_data": "Button5"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Button6",
        "callback_data": "Button6"
      }]
    ]
  }

  if (contents.callback_query) {

    var chat_id = contents.callback_query.from.id;
    var user = contents.callback_query.message.chat.first_name + " " + contents.callback_query.message.chat.last_name;
    var cb_data = contents.callback_query.data;

    var ssId = "SPREADSHEET_ID";
    var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Foglio2");
    var sh2range = sh2.getRange(1, 1, sh2.getLastRow(), sh2.getLastColumn());
    var sh2values = sh2range.getValues();
    var sh2values_len = sh2values.length;
    var cocktail_nome;
    for (i = 0; i < sh2values_len; i++) {
      cocktail_nome = sh2values[i][0] + '';
      if (cb_data == cocktail_nome.toLowerCase()) {
        answer = "Ingredienti: " + sh2values[i][1] + '.' + '%0A' + "Preparazione: " + sh2values[i][2];
        break;
      }
    }

    sendMessage(chat_id, answer);
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Foglio1").appendRow([new Date(), chat_id, user, cb_data]);

  } else if (contents.message) {

    var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
    var user = contents.message.chat.first_name + " " + contents.message.chat.last_name;

    var answer = "Ciao " + user + ". Seleziona il nome di un cocktail e ti dirò come prepararlo!";
    sendKeyboard(chat_id, answer, keyboard);

  }
}
```